# How declare type which includes only available event names based on EventEmitter descendant passed to class or function

Tags: node.js, typescript, eventemitter

I'm trying to create class or function which can unsubscribe from event automatically.
The problem, that I can't to infer available event names basing on passed target.

In that case compiler tells: Argument of type '"data"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"timeout"'. Seems compiler see only one of overloads for method 'on' of target process.stdin

I expected that  will be a union of type:
'close' | 'connect' | 'data' | 'drain' | 'end' | 'error' | 'lookup' | 'ready' |'timeout';

Is there any legal solution?

($tsc -v
Version 4.7.3)

```
import EventEmitter from "events";

class ConditionRemovableSubscriber<
  T extends EventEmitter,
  E extends Parameters<T['on']>[0]
> {
  constructor(
    readonly target: T,
    readonly eventName: E,
    ... otherArgs: any[]
  ) {
  }

}

const check = new ConditionRemovableSubscriber(process.stdin, 'data');
```

Comment: Since `on` uses overloads... you need a looooooooong type to infer them all (up to a maximum number): https://tsplay.dev/wOAOlm (and no I did not type this out myself - I wrote [some code](https://tsplay.dev/mL2pvw) to do it)